# To replace a word within a sentence/string in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to use excel power query to replace a word in a sentence.

For example, I would like to replace **"South Korea"** to **"Korea"**

Original:

| ID | Primary Location | Other Locations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | United States | South Korea, Japan |
| 002 | United Kingdom | France, United States, South Korea |
| 003 | France | United Kingdom |
| 004 | Australia | Japan |
| 005 | Japan | South Korea |

After Power Query:

| ID | Primary Location | Other Locations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | United States | Korea, Japan |
| 002 | United Kingdom | France, United States, Korea |
| 003 | France | United Kingdom |
| 004 | Australia | Japan |
| 005 | Japan | Korea |

I tried to use the

```
Table.ReplaceValue(#"Step1","South Korea","Korea",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Other Locations"})
```

But it only gave me

| ID | Primary Location | Other Locations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | United States | South Korea, Japan |
| 002 | United Kingdom | France, United States, South Korea |
| 003 | France | United Kingdom |
| 004 | Australia | Japan |
| 005 | Japan | Korea |

Are there ways that I can replace all the **"South Korea"** to **"Korea"** within the same column?

Thank you.

Comment: That last part should be `"Other Locations"` not `"Other Location"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your syntax is perfect

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Step1","South Korea","Korea",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Other Locations"})
```

that means you have another error somewhere

(a) Your sample columns says "Other Locations" your formula says "Other Location". They are not the same

(b) Maybe **#"Step1"** is not the name of the original data. Are you sure?

Right click the column and use replace text option. It will write the code for you

Comment: (a) its a typo and I have corrected it.

Comment: (b) #"Step1" is the previous step in the power query, and when I save and load, there's no error shown but it gave me the third table instead of the second table shown above

Comment: oh its just that the preview doesnt refreshed and I thought mine is wrong. Thank you